# Visual Studio 2017 "Go To Definition" for partial classes

Tags: visual-studio-2017, partial-classes, go-to-definition

In our solution, we work with many partial classes. The implementation is spread over 2 files, whereas one of the files only contains auto generated code.

When I press F12 (Go to Definition) on instances of such classes, VS 2017 displays a list of declarations (2 files) instead directly opening the "non auto-generated" file, like older VS versions do.

How can I get the old behavior again with VS 2017?

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Assist](https://www.wholetomato.com/) : Visual Assist has a wealth of features to enhance developer productivity.